# Request is always null in web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API with a Base Controller, I wanna get requested controller name from `Request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"]`, as the following code :

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    protected string EntityName;

    public BaseApiController()
    {
        //Request is null
        EntityName = Request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string;
    }
}
```

But Request is always null in above code.
What's wrong with above code?

Comment: There is no request yet.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? May be there is a better way.

Comment: @SLaks: You mean we can't use Request in BaseController constructor method?

Comment: @Shyju: Do you know the better way for getting requested controller in `BaseController`?

Comment: Define your requirement more specific.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected - you're in the controllers constructor.  The controller hasn't been initialized with the actual request yet.  Try something like the following:

```
protected string EntityName 
{
  get { Request.GetRouteData().Values["controller"] as string; }
}
```

That should be accessible *after* the constructor has run, and when you're in a subclass method.

Answer (score 6):

You just cannot use the `Request` property in the `Controller`'s c'tor. It gets called before the actual request is handed over to it by the framework.

Comment: So, How can I get requested URL or requested controller in base controller ?

Comment: The requested URL: no (there's no way to get it before you're in the action method). Concrete controller type: Simply use 'typeof(this)'.

Comment: what if I need to call GetOwinContext? I was planning to use it to get DB context and UserManager

Answer (score 3):

If you need Headers, you can use HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers